# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have the following class to store data.

```
namespace SumSoftware
{
    public class Faculty
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Dept { get; set; }
        public List<string> subInterest;

    }
}
```

And I am trying to add data from a ListBox and User Input in this fashion.

```
private void btnTeacherDataAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> interests = new List<string>();
    if (lstInterest.SelectedItems.Count >= 0)
    {
        foreach (var selectedSubjects in lstInterest.SelectedItems)
        {
                interests.Add(selectedSubjects.ToString());
        }
    }

    SaveDirectory.list_of_faculty.Add(
        new Faculty {
            Name = txtTeacherName.Text, 
            Dept = cmbDepts.Items.CurrentItem.ToString(),
            subInterest = new List<string>().AddRange(interests) //ERROR HERE
        });
}
```

I am unable to store the contents of the ListBox in my list. How can this be mended?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than calling `AddRange` on a list to initialize it with a sequence of values, pass the sequence into the constructor:

```
subInterest = new List<string>(interests),
```

The `AddRange` method returns `void`, not the list itself, and you're trying to assign that `void` expression to `subInterest`, which isn't valid.